# Does the type of play on words in "Some people are immune to good advice" have a name?

Tags: word-usage, rhetoric, literary-techniques, humor

On Breaking Bad, Saul Goodman remarks, "Some people are immune to good advice." Similarly, a friend of mine described a weekend as "a celebration of procrastination".

Does word play that juxtaposes the verb and the object, as the examples above do, have a name?

Answer (score 3):

The phrases have an **[oxymoronic](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/oxymoron)** quality to them

> a figure of speech in which opposite or contradictory ideas or terms are combined (Ex.: thunderous silence, sweet sorrow)

In the examples given, the modifiers are incongruously linked to terms that belie them. One is generally immune to bad things, not good, and one celebrates the positive, not the negative.

Answer (score 0):

*Figurative language*,

Departing from a literal use of words; metaphorical:
gold, in the figurative language of the people, was “the tears wept by the sun.”

Source: Oxfordonline

Comment: I meant to refer to the humorous contrast between the verb and their objects realized by their unusual collocations.